# Прозрачность

Tags: html, css

Народ помогите. На фоновом изображении хочу наложить блок с прозрачным фоном, но чтоб все элементы в нем не были прозрачными (то есть свойство opacity мне не поможет). Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Ну можно же прозрачный фон сделать на отдельном слое. Т.е. два слоя - первый прозрачный, второй с контентом не прозрачный. Оба слоя с абсолютным позиционированием по всей площади исходного блока.

Либо фон сделать через rgba(...)

[Здесь примеры](http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/poluprozrachnyi-fon)

Comment: спс . буду пробывать позиционирование

Answer (score 3):

*тут должен быть текст про использование поиска*

```
background:rgba(R,G,B,A)
```

`R`, `G`, `B` — цвет, `A` — прозрачность.

Comment: дело в том что я rgba не поможет, т.к. мой полупрозрачный фон это пиксель который repeat-ом растягиваю по ширине блока.

Comment: @Drylozav 

    background-color: rgba(R,G,B,A);

Comment: Ну так выкиньте свой полупрозрачный пиксель — у все есть RGBA.